# Revealing Module Pattern with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, revealing-module-pattern

Today code is driving me mad again especially the Angular with the Revealing Module Pattern in an Angular service. When I started I saw nothing wrong with it... now apart from not working... I don't know. Any way know I want to know if it's angular or me doing something stupid. here's the code:

```
angular.module('homeAdmin.services', [])
.factory('dataService', function ($http, $q) {
    'use strict';
    function _contentTypes(){
        var intialized = false;
        var _models = [];
        function _isReady() {
            return intialized;
        };
        return {
            isReady: _isReady
        };
    };

    return {
        contentTypes: _contentTypes
    };
});
```

And here's where it is called:

```
var contentTypeCtrl = ['$scope','$http','$window','dataService', function ($scope, $http, $window, dataService) {
'use strict';
$scope.isBusy = false;
$scope.data = dataService;
$scope.contentType = {};

$scope.name = 'Content Type';
$scope.init = function () {
    console.log('contentTypeCtrl initialized');
};

if (dataService.contentTypes.isReady() == false) {
    console.log("Hello let's load some data!"); 
}}]
```

And here's how firefox gives me the finger:

```
[16:01:56.864] "Error: dataService.contentTypes.isReady is not a function
contentTypeCtrl<@http://localhost:49499/App/plugins/home/admin/ngen/content-type-ctrl.js:12
invoke@http://localhost:49499/Scripts/angular/angular.js:2902
instantiate@http://localhost:49499/Scripts/angular/angular.js:2914
@http://localhost:49499/Scripts/angular/angular.js:4805
updateView@http://localhost:49499/Scripts/angular/angular-ui-router.js:1317
$ViewDirective/directive.compile/</eventHook@http://localhost:49499/Scripts/angular/angular-ui-router.js:1276
Scope.prototype.$broadcast@http://localhost:49499/Scripts/angular/angular.js:8307
$StateProvider/$get/transitionTo/$state.transition<@http://localhost:49499/Scripts/angular/angular-ui-router.js:1067
qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then/wrappedCallback@http://localhost:49499/Scripts/angular/angular.js:6846
qFactory/ref/<.then/<@http://localhost:49499/Scripts/angular/angular.js:6883
Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:49499/Scripts/angular/angular.js:8057
Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:49499/Scripts/angular/angular.js:7922
Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:49499/Scripts/angular/angular.js:8143
done@http://localhost:49499/Scripts/angular/angular.js:9170
completeRequest@http://localhost:49499/Scripts/angular/angular.js:9333
createHttpBackend/</xhr.onreadystatechange@http://localhost:49499/Scripts/angular/angular.js:9304"
```

Help? Anyone??

Here's an example how the isready function should be used:

```
    if (dataService.contentTypes.isReady() == false) {
    $scope.isBusy = true;
    dataService.contentTypes.get()
        .then(function () {
        }, function () {
            alert('contentTypes retrieval failed');
        })
        .then(function () {
            $scope.isBusy = false;
        });
}
```

And consume the data like this:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="model in data.contentTypes.models">
```

Comment: Are you sure that dataservice has been loaded up when you are testing against it's containing values?  Also, I have never double nested functions like this with AMD but what is the result when you use dataservice.contentTypes().isReady() ?

Comment: Yes a break point on the first line of the controller shows that dataService is fully injected and ready to go... What do you mean with "What's the result"? Current usage results in the exception given above. Functionally the IsReady() function would be to check if the dataService has the data for this set already loaded.

Comment: Basically I meant what happens when you do this (added an extra parans to the contentTypes), the user1566994 guy below just hijacked what I said and made it into an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not proficient with Angular, so excuse me if I'm way off here (-!

It looks like isReady() is returned by calling contentTypes() - but I don't see a call to contentTypes - only a reference, which points to the closure-fn _contentTypes.

Is it possible that this should read like below instead ?

```
dataService.contentTypes().isReady()
```

*added '()' to actually call the contentTypes function, which in turn will return the isReady() function

Comment: Nailed it in one ... Thanks! You don't happen to know what I should change to be able to omit those "()" ?

Comment: This is a valid answer, I don't get it why it was down-voted ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the Module Revealing Pattern with Factories,
It will only return the default value of properties when instantiated.
You need to use services if you want to use the modules revealing pattern.